# Ubuntu not install on Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7

First time on forum and using ubuntu. I checked and didnt see this issue.

I downloaded and burned ubuntu 12.04 x64 on a cd , restarted computer, and booted from cd.

boot went normally through all the options, connected to WiFi , chose to install ubuntu alongside windows.

at beginning of installation, dvd drive opened and a message popped up saying to remove installation media, close drive and press enter.

followed instructions, and computer then proceeded to boot windows with no installation taking place...

what should I do?

running Toshiba Satellite laptop with core2duo @2.0 Ghz 4 Gb RAM Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this is a grub-boot-loader issue.

Visit the [Ubuntu Wiki to read about Grub.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Hopefully your problem will be solved with this tool : [Boot-Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) Follow the 2nd option.

Comment: Tried to update and run boot-repair while in "try ubuntu." terminal said a long string of code i didnt fully understand, and at the end had trouble with "launchpad.net"

I would have copied all of it, but I took a screenshot thinking I could upload it here.... guess not.

Anyways, command line option did not seem to work, and yes I triple-checked that I copied command correctly.

Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Zat

Comment: It's easier to use a CD with Boot-Repair preinstalled, for example [Ubuntu-Secure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix). Concerning the screenshot, you can upload it on http://tinypic.com/ then tell us the link here.

Comment: Ubuntu-Secure did allow me to run boot-repair, and proceed with installation, however, there was no "alongside" option, only overwrite or partition. 

So I had to read some tutorials on safe partitioning, but I got it working. 

I'm typing this post from within my new ubuntu OS! Thanks to both of you for quick and useful responses.  Great Forum, and I'm looking forward to joining the community.

Cheers,